# How to get the MousePosition while Drag&Drop? (WPF-MVVM)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, drag-and-drop

So basically I followed [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/420545/WPF-Drag-and-Drop-MVVM-using-Behavior) example to create my own Drag&Drop. I want to be able to drag an Object from one View to another (UserControls inside MainWindow) and place it at the current mouse location relative to the view in which I dropped my Element.

I tried using this code in my FrameworkElementBehavior:

```
private void AssociatedObject_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        CanItDropHere(e,
            canDrop: () =>
            {
                var type = _allowedDropTypes.First(t => e.Data.GetDataPresent(t));
                var draggedItem = e.Data.GetData(type) as IDragable;
                var position = e.GetPosition(App.Current.MainWindow);

                var droppedOn = AssociatedObject.DataContext as IDropableWithMousePos;
                droppedOn?.Drop(draggedItem,position);
            });


        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

However here I get the Mouse Position relative to my MainWindow. This leads to the problem that the object gets dopped with an offset which is obvious. However I have no clue how to get the Position realtive to the view in which I drop.

Answer (score 0):

Working Solution:

```
var position = e.GetPosition(sender as IInputElement);
```